# I want a string with five letters if the domain is having string length less then 5,i want to concat the randomly generated strings with domain name

Tags: php

```
$domain = strtok($domain_name, '.');

if (strlen($domain) <= "5")
{
    $user_name = substr($domain . $filler);
}
else
{
    $user_name = substr($domain, 0, 5);
}
```

My logic is not working properly in this case.

Comment: We need more info. What is the value of `$domain_name`? What should be the value of `$user_name`?

Comment: change `strlen($domain) <= "5"` to `strlen($domain) <= 5`. strlen() returns integer

Comment: Why do you compare strlen which outputs a integer with "5", a string?

Comment: @Abhishek and anyone who upvoted their comment, PHP will convert the strong "5" to an integer 5 when doing doing the comparison  due to [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) so this is *not* this  issue.

Comment: @John off course not. But that is not the point. In this case it will work but it's good to have an habbit to compare apples with apples.

Comment: @Andreas Sure. The comment left above implies it is the cause of their problems and it should be clear that it is not.

Comment: Can you please give us an example with the desired output? Show us an example of what `$domain_name` or  `$filler` can be. And when you say "is not properly working in this case", what error do you get?

Comment: @Linga never walk away after asking a question. Your window for getting an answer is essentially closed and your chances of solving this problem just became a whole lot smaller.

Comment: lets say i am having domain name li.com,all i need to do is get "li" from $domain_name and another 3 letters from $filler(which is randomly generated string.

Comment: Is it possible to make one pass login to whm and cpanel in php,available code in online is not working.